# Как сбросить ключи при фильтре массива?

Tags: php, массивы

Удаляется пустные значения после разбития строки на слэш

```
$str = '/a/b//';
$result = array_filter(explode('/', $str), 'strlen'); // [1=>a,2=>b]
```

Из примера выше нужно получить `[0=>a,1=>b]` желательно без цикла с новым массивом

Comment: `strlen` тут не нужен, пустые строки отфильтруются без коллбэка вовсе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> желательно без цикла с новым массивом

Без цикла тут не обойтись:

```
$result = array_values($result);
```